# VS 2015 Publishing Issues

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, publishing

I can build and debug my project (Web Forms App / VS 2015) but when I attempt to publish I don't get any errors (in the standard errors panel) but in the output window I see I do and the publish fails, but the build runs !?!?!?!?

Each of the types do exist and the namespacing is correct, I have no idea why these issues are stopping me from publishing ?!?!?!?!

[image: Publishing Issues]

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed itself, I didn't do anything or make any significant changes.